# Как изменять IP в запросах в Charles?

Tags: c#, charles

Не могу разобраться как изменять IP в запросах в чарльзе.

Попробую объяснить - есть софт на C# использую dotnetbrowser. Знаю что в чарльзе можно изменять запрос и IP но как не могу уже три дня понять. Если кто - то знает объясните. Мне нужно в каждом запросе (а их много)менять IP

Comment: У вас очень сбивчивое объяснение проблемы. И поясните, пожалуйста, для незнающих, что такое `Charles`?

Comment: https://www.charlesproxy.com/  . Charles proxy для веб отладки

Comment: Прокси - это посредник, вот что написано: `Charles to inspect and change requests as they pass from the client to the server, and the response as it passes from the server to the client.`, т.е. он просто "сидит" на канале и слушает трафик, все запросы на нужные адреса вы должны выполнять с помощью вашего `dotnetbrowser`.

Comment: `ip` меняется сам - конечно, если вы, сидите под `NAT` - где динамический `ip`. Который меняется в заданном интервале в вашем роутере. - Но если вам нужно менять `ip` программно, вам придется зализать в реестр до `TcpIp` - где `IpAddress` - ваш `ip`, а `SubnetMask` - маска подсети. Еще можно попробовать через `Ip Helper`.